# Use PHP code in .TPL files in Kohana/Smarty Framework

Tags: php, frameworks, smarty, kohana

I am unable to write PHP code in .tpl file in either ways

I tried `<?php echo 'test'; ?>`

I also tried `{PHP} echo 'test'; {/PHP}`

But both returned error

```
on line 14 "{php}echo &quot;hello!&quot;{/php}" unknown tag "php"
```

Comment: Do you use Kohana and Smarty? If so, why (not only one of them)?

Comment: @kingkero - I am really not sure but I think Kohana is derived from Smarty. As the project shows its developed in Kohana but the errors says "Smarty Framework". So, I am thinking Kohana is derived from Smarty and both may have great relationship.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Smarty, but your first try would be no problem working with regular Views (in Kohana)

Answer (score 2):

I've not worked with Kohana, but with Smarty 3, use of the [php tag is deprecated](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.php.tpl). You'll need to use the [backwards compatibility](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/bc.tpl) mode with 3.0. It is highly recommended that all code logic be placed in your controller or php script files, and not your Smarty templates.

If you want to use PHP code in templates, it is suggested you create [custom functions](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.functions.tpl) or [modifiers](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.modifiers.tpl).

So, basically, the short answer is find where your code (or the Kohana plugin) is instantiating Smarty and change it to use SmartyBC, but be aware that this is highly discouraged.

If you are using Kohana Smarty3 module for Kohana, [these code lines](https://github.com/MrAnchovy/Kohana_Smarty3/blob/da9b39234fb7fc8936e3d965402527c1d8a29829/classes/Smarty/View.php#L253-L264) should help set you in the right direction.

Comment: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/bc.tpl I just read this before but wondering in which file I should change this?

Comment: Edited my answer... basically, change from Smarty to SmartyBC on 255 and 263. But, I have no idea if this is the module you're using or not.

Comment: I asked in which file I should make this edit http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/bc.tpl